# How do I change \r in the file path in python?

Tags: python

If I type the file path e.g. C:\abc\abc\robinhood, the part \r becomes an issue, because robinhood starts with "r". How can I fix this problem? Thank you.

Comment: BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48618218/how-to-escape-escape-characters